# Google Drive picker login/load issues

Tags: google-drive-api, picker

We've integrated the Google Drive picker into our product, and mostly have no issues. However, we have a user that keeps running into issues - the picker will sometimes prompt for login and then fail after that (it will work for a little while, but after some amount of time they always run into this). They are seeing this issue on a daily basis. I am providing as much info on these as I currently have:

This is the original issue the user was seeing. User attempts to open picker. Picker prompts user to sign-in. After sign-in, user is returned to the previous page inside the picker, but the sign-in button is still displaying. Clicking on sign-in again results in one of the following:
Scenario 1: a 404
Scenario 2: a broken page with the message "docs.google.com refused to connect"

They have had to reload the whole site in order to see the picker working again

Relevant code for displaying the picker is as follows:

```
api.spawnFilePicker = (options = {}) => {
    const { callback, multiSelect = true, selectType = 'files', title } = options;
    const { google, gapi } = window.parent;

    const pickerNs = google && google.picker;
    if (!pickerNs) {
        if (gapi) {
            return gapi.load('picker', () => api.spawnFilePicker(options));
        }

        console.error(
            '[GoogleDriveClient] No window.parent.google.picker or window.parent.gapi defined!'
        );
        return;
    }

    const view = new pickerNs.DocsView();

    if (selectType === 'folders') {
        view.setIncludeFolders(true);
        view.setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
        view.setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
    }

    const builder = new pickerNs.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(pickerNs.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        .setOAuthToken(api.getAccessToken()) //user's access token
        .addView(view);

    title && builder.setTitle(title);

    if (callback) {
        builder.setCallback(callback);
    }

    if (multiSelect) {
        builder.enableFeature(pickerNs.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED);
    }

    if (selectType === 'folders') {
        builder.setSelectableMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
    }

    const picker = builder.build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code you are using to reproduce this? Is it based on [this example](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs#example)? Is this failing only for one specific user? It works for any other user, using the exact same code? Is this user from your same domain? Also, about the different scenarios, do they happen alternatively, without any change on your side?

Comment: @Iamblichus I've updated the code to include the full function. I don't believe the code was based off of any specific example. This user is the only one who has brought up the issue, and can fix it by either refreshing the page or deactivating/reactivating our custom Google integration. Domain is the same for all users. For the scenarios, user says he's taking same steps each time, but second scenario started happening more recently. Has not mentioned first scenario since second started. We have changed nothing on our end. Last change to this part of the code was 10 months ago.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the context in which this is being executed, so that this can be reproduced? Also, when you say `This user is the only one who has brought up the issue`, does it mean you cannot reproduce it?

Comment: @Iamblichus sure, this is in our email client. Feel free to sign up with a trial account for Zimbra Cloud at zimbracloud.com. Once you're in, go to Settings > Google Drive to enable Google Drive. Then, create a new email and click the attach icon. A menu will pop up that will include the option to add files from Google drive. Either choose to attach a file or insert a link, either will open the picker. 

As to `This user is the only one who has brought up the issue` - you are correct that I and no one on my team that has tried have been able to reproduce this.

Comment: Is the user's account a gmail account or a G Suite or other?

Comment: @Aerials it is a standard gmail account

Comment: The user has given me access to the account, and I am able to reproduce. We are calling https://docs.google.com/picker, and including the following params: protocol, origin, navHidden, multiSelectEnabled, hostId, parent, nav, rpcService, rpcToken, thirdParty. All params exist, and look valid.